# Representing a range in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm a beginner at Processing, and I was wondering if there is a function that represents an interval of values? In java, I think it's IntRange, but what's the equivalent in Processing?

Comment: in addition to Kevin's answer, you can use java libraries in Processing, for example [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html). His solution however, is simpler(if you just need to keep track of a pair of values) and will work in other modes(e.g. Processing's JavaScript mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not have an IntRange class. You might be best off just creating your own class:

```
class Range{
   int low;
   int high;

   public Range(int low, int high){
      this.low = low;
      this.high = high;
   }
}
```